# Get index of first character apperence without extension functions?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to find index of an character in SQLite without using extension functions?

I need to substring texts like below from the beginning until `(` character in a SELECT statement.

- `TT 15 (Something...)`
- `TT 5 (blabla...)`

I cannot use `instr` in our version of SQLite (i think it is 3.6) and it's not possible to update SQLite either.

Comment: What is the exact version of SQLite you use?

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible to do something like `instr()` without actually calling `instr()`, the authors of SQLite would not have felt the need to add `instr()`.

If you cannot update SQLite or create an extension function, you have to read the entire string from the database and search it in your own code.